# using ajax/jquery to lookup address using postcode?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have found this pretty amazing script which will lookup an address using the postcode. It works on the JsFiddle but when I try to implement it into a page on my site it doesn't do anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/rxFBj/3/

My Code:

```
<form name="request">
    <p>Fill out the postcode and hit search</p>

        <input name="address1" placeholder="address 1" /><br />
        <input name="custom_field"  placeholder="address 2" /><br />
        <input name="address3"  placeholder="address 3" /><br />
        <input name="address4"  placeholder="address 4" /><br />
        <input class="postcode" name="postcode"  placeholder="Postcode" /><br />
    </form>







     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>     
     <script>
    /*fill out the postcode and hit search*/
    (function($) {
        $.fn.searchPc = function(options) {

            var settings = $.extend({
                address1: 'address1',
                address2: 'address2',
                address3: 'address3',
                address4: 'address4'
            }, options);

            return this.each(function() {

                var $el = $(this);
                var $form = $el.closest('form');

                //insert the button on the form
                $('<a class="postCodeLookup">Search</a>').insertAfter($el);
                $('.postCodeLookup', $form).button({icons:{primary:'ui-icon-search'}});

                $form.on('click', '.postCodeLookup', function() {

                    $.post('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+$el.val()+'&sensor=false', function(r) {
                        var lat = r['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
                        var lng = r['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
                        $.post('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+lat+','+lng+'&sensor=false', function(address) {
                            $('input[name='+settings.address1+']').val(address['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['long_name']);
                            $('input[name='+settings.address2+']').val(address['results'][0]['address_components'][1]['long_name']);
                            $('input[name='+settings.address3+']').val(address['results'][0]['address_components'][2]['long_name']);
                            $('input[name='+settings.address4+']').val(address['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['long_name']);
                        });
                    });

                });



            });
        };
    })(jQuery);


            $('input[name=postcode]').searchPc({
                address2: 'custom_field',
            });

    </script>
```

Please can someone show me if I am doing something wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look in your JavaScript console. Watch it complain about `$` being undefined.

You've loaded jQuery-UI (twice!) but not jQuery and all your code depends on jQuery.

Comment: 2.x if you don't care about old IE. 1.x if you do.

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
so is this right? I should be loading this jquery library?

Comment: No, you should use the latest version unless you have a good reason not to. http://jquery.com/download/ - it's 2.1.4 at present.

Comment: ok so I have updated my question to reflect the changes you advised but it's still not working?

Comment: Again: Look at your JavaScript console. `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).button is not a function`. jQuery doesn't have a `button` method. You probably get it from some other library. You need to include it. Your JS Fiddle loads jQuery UI but now you don't include that at all in the code you're running.